# Пакеты файлов в php

Tags: php

Есть ли такое в php? Чтобы не нужно было инклудить много файлов с классами, а, если они в одном пакете, то их и так можно использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файлы друг о друге знать не могут, но вы можете использовать [Автозагрузку классов](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php)

[лучше с помощью spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

```
function __autoload($className)
{
    $fname = str_replace('_', '/', $className) . '.php';
    $result = include_once($fname);
    return $result;
}
```